# Urlrewriter.net matching rule returns to much

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

This is our rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite url="/Product/(.+)/" to="~/ProductDetails?ProductID=$1" />
```

and it works fine for

```
www.website.com/product/34/nice-red-jacket
```

then we get `ProductID=34`

But it fails as soon as there is another forward slash in the url

```
www.website.com/product/34/nice-red-jacket/special-edition/buy-now/
```

results in `ProductID=34%2fnice-red-jacket%2fspecial-edition%2fbuy-now`

We need to change our rewrite rule to stop matching at the first/next slash, but how do we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this expression

```
^/Product/(\d+)/?.*$

<rewrite url="^/Product/(\d+)/?.*$" to="~/ProductDetails?ProductID=$1" />
```

The first group `(\d+)` means to match at least one digit, which represents the ID, that can be followed or not by a `/` and then by any character. `^ and $` marks the begin and the end of the match.

Here some test data

```
var reg = new Regex(@"^/Product/(\d+)/?.*$");

var urls = new []
    { 
        "/Product/1",
        "/Product/2/23/asd",
        "/Product/3/21334/asd/",
        "/Product/5/32/asd/asd",           
    };

urls.Select(url=> reg.Replace(url,"~/ProductDetails?ProductID=${1}"))
    .Dump();
```